# How to use built-in logging in dnx?

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, dnx, built-in

Is it possible to use built-in logging to file in dnx?
I tried to use `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener` but is not available in .Net Core. Any suggestions?

Comment: Serilog has a file sink and rolling file sink, and works with .NET Core.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35052615/409259

Comment: Thanks good example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, ASP.NET Core’s logging system does not come with a file-based logging provider.

It would be pretty simple to roll your own though; just look at the [Debug logger](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug) as an example to see what you need to do.

Of course, you could also use another logging framework that already supports this. For example [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) – a .NET Core compatible version is [in alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.4.0-alpha1). Another example would be [Serilog](http://serilog.net/) which also has .NET Core versions in beta (versions 2.x)

If you run your app through IIS, you can also use IIS’ file logging to redirect the stdout logging into files. This can be configured in the `web.config`.

Comment: Have you found any working examples NLog with dnxcore50? All examples I found run on dnx451 like this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/samples/SampleApp)

Comment: I’d guess that you just have to change the `project.json` to reference the alpha version of NLog.